# How can I extract the data from a remote text file and display it on my website?

Tags: php

I have been trying to extract the data from this text file and display it on my own website. Here is the link to the file: http://shotbow.net/serverList.txt

Every time there is a comma that is a new bit of data for a different thing. Can someone please show me how to display these different bits of info wherever I like on my webpage, they need to auto update as well.

So to sum it up, after every comma is a new bit of data. I need to be able to display each bit of data individually wherever I choose on my website. It also needs to be auto updating. It would be ideal if this could be done in PHP as well.

Comment: Can you add your code to show what you've tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: Well, i'm not completely sure about all the code that would be needed to do this. Thats why I came here for help.

Answer (score 1):

First, use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) or ([`cURL`](http://php.net/curl)) to retrieve the file contents:

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents('http://shotbow.net/serverList.txt');
// perform some checks to make sure f_g_c call was successful
```

Now that you have the contents of the file, you can try to parse it. The values are comma-separated, for e.g.

```
1548,133,100,24,45,871,5,100,34,26,9,59
```

You can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to split this string with comma as the delimiter:

```
$array = explode(',', $fileContents);
```

Now, to display it on your site, simply use a loop:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    // $value contains the value - display it
}
```

Now when the script (page) is loaded, the values from the remote file will be retrieved, parsed, and displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://shotbow.net/serverList.txt');
if ($contents === false) {
    echo 'Error getting server list';
} else {
    $servers = explode(',', $contents);
    foreach ($servers as $server) {
        // Output the server
        echo $server;
    }
}
```

Is this the sort of thing you're thinking of?